# Pandas Split into multiple columns and unpiviot

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am trying to split multiple columns based on a delimiter and then unpivot those columns.

df:

```
                         Technique_Name Technique_ID                                       Threat_Actor                                       Threat_Tools
0     Abuse Elevation Control Mechanism        T1548                                                NaN                                                NaN
1                     Setuid and Setgid    T1548.001                                                NaN                                                NaN
2           Bypass User Account Control    T1548.002  Honeybee,BRONZEBUTLER,APT29,CobaltGroup,MuddyW...                                            PowerSploit,pwdump,Mimikatz,netstat,Ping,FTP
3                 Sudo and Sudo Caching    T1548.003                                                NaN                                                NaN
4        Elevated Execution with Prompt    T1548.004                                                NaN                                                NaN
```

i am using the following code to split out the columns:

```
Threat_Tools = max(list(map(lambda x: len(x.split(",")),df.Threat_Tools)))
Threat_Actor = max(list(map(lambda x: len(x.split(",")),df.Threat_Actor)))
cols = ["Tools"+str(x) for x in range(Threat_Tools)]
cols1 = ["Actor"+str(x) for x in range(Threat_Actor)]
datalist = list(map(lambda x: x.split(","), df.Threat_Tools))
datalist2 = list(map(lambda x: x.split(","), df.Threat_Actor))
```

I then want to unpivot the Actor and Tools based on the TechID/Name

Desired Output:

```
                     Technique_Name Technique_ID                                       Threat_Actor                                       Threat_Tools
 Abuse Elevation Control Mechanism        T1548                                                NaN                                                NaN
                 Setuid and Setgid    T1548.001                                                NaN                                                NaN
       Bypass User Account Control    T1548.002                                           Honeybee                                          PowerSploit
       Bypass User Account Control    T1548.002                                       BRONZEBUTLER                                          pwdump
       Bypass User Account Control    T1548.002                                              APT29                                            Mimikatz
       Bypass User Account Control    T1548.002                                        CobaltGroup                                            netstat
       Bypass User Account Control    T1548.002                                               MuddyW                                            Ping
             Sudo and Sudo Caching    T1548.003                                                NaN                                                NaN
    Elevated Execution with Prompt    T1548.004                                                NaN                                                NaN
```

Comment: Please provide at least some sample of the actual dataframe as well as sample of the expected output.

Comment: You can check out `.split(expand=True)` which is helpful for splitting to multiple columns. But no one can help you until we know what the problem is - what the input and expected output is.

Comment: What does your outputs look like ?

Comment: The output is on the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = df.join(df['Threat_Actor'].str.split(',', expand=True).add_prefix('Actor'))
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x + x[-1] if x.startswith('Actor') else x)
df = df.join(df['Threat_Tools'].str.split(',', expand=True).add_prefix('Tools'))
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x + x[-1] if x.startswith('Tools') else x)
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, ['Actor', 'Tools'], i=['Technique_ID'], j='i')
df['Tools'] = df['Tools'].ffill()
df = df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

This allows me to split the columns and then merge them all into multiple rows as per the desired output.